# Wordpress - import database from the old theme to the new theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site which is live and running. I want to change the theme but I'm new to wordpress and what I'm trying to do is that I have a new theme setup locally(I want to play around with it before putting it live) and I want to import the database from the live site to my new theme locally. What is the correct way to do this ? I tried to export the database and import it but nothing is working anymore after this.

Themes are totally different. Should I import just the posts and comment? (basically this is what I need from the old one). How can I do this ? 
I'm not sure how to proceed further..

Comment: Are you able to get a complete copy of your database from the production server onto your local machine? (What method are you using?) Also, did you remember to update the wp_options table to use your local domain name?

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin - import/export. No, I didn't update the wp_options for my local domain(I'm not familiar with the wp database but I will modify this for my local domain). Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: ok, that seems to work in some way but doesn't look right and I see some errors on admin panel. The only thing I need is to import posts/comments and that's it. How can I do only that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On live site:

- Login and goto Tools > Export > All content

On local site:

- Delete all posts, categories, tags, pages and comments, and empty trash.
- Goto Tools > Import > WordPress, and select the XML file, import attachments if you need when it asks.
- Delete anything that you don't need, and empty trash.

Comment: awesome, this was what I needed. Now I have all my posts in the new theme and have to work on home and the new pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can export the whole database then import it in phpmyadmin  or whatever you use to manage the database then update the configuration file in the local wordpress folder to make it able to connect the local database you imported,  if you can't do so what are the errors you get that prevent you ?

Comment: the import is successful, there is no error, but when I access the site locally nothing happens after the import, just a blank page. Kyle said something about updating the wp_option table for new domain. I'll try that..